# pandas rearrange columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, transpose

i have a dataframe df which has 2 rows  and 3 columns a,b,c like below :

```
   A     B     C     
0  1.1   1.2   1.3
1  3.1   3.5   3.9
```

Required output :I want like below without needing column headers

```
0  1.1
   1.2
   1.3
1  3.1
   3.5
   3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create the dataframe that OP is using

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [3.1, 3.5, 3.9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Now, in order to convert the columns into rows, this has a special name "transposition", and one can use [`dataframe.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) as follows

```
df = df.transpose()
```

or [`dataframe.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) (`T` is an accessor for the `transpose` method)

```
df = df.T
```

The final result is

```
print(df)

[Out]:
     0    1
A  1.1  3.1
B  1.2  3.5
C  1.3  3.9
```

Given [this new requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076004/pandas-rearrange-columns-into-rows/72076177?noredirect=1#comment127352908_72076177) that OP mentioned, if one wants to concat the second column under the first column, the following will do the work

```
df = df[0].append(df[1]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)

[Out]:
0    1.1
1    1.2
2    1.3
3    3.1
4    3.5
5    3.9
```